# CSV to MySQL conversion and import

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Im working on a large project, havent had to do what I need help with before. I have a csv file, it contains a large amount of data, namely all of the cities, towns, suburbs in Australia. I need to convert the csv file to sql for mysql, and then import it into the database.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) or the equivalent command-line tool [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html).

These are easy to use for loading CSV data, and this method runs 20x faster than importing rows one at a time with SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I did try to use the LOAD DATA INFILE method, but it would not accept my path to the csv file. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Lea - This is the way to go. What is the problem with the path ? +1

Comment: @Romain Hippeau it simply returns the error "csv file not found". I tried to use the absolute path to the file, but it doesnt seem to accept it.

Comment: @Lea can you run it from the location where your csv file is located ?

Comment: Try `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` otherwise it wants the file to be under the MySQL Server's data directory.

Comment: @Lea - Did you try Bill's idea above ?